# Testing Asyncio with Pytest: How to test a try-except block by mocking the event loop?

Tags: python, pytest, python-asyncio, monkeypatching, pytest-asyncio

In a source code ([source link here](https://github.com/OpenMined/PySyft/blob/56fa8ef7d6a154482570b2d8b4580b544848837f/src/syft/grid/connections/webrtc.py#L123-L156) and [WIP PR here](https://github.com/OpenMined/PySyft/blob/989b4418c5df516cdd1355ad736e3bbfc2ac83e4/tests/syft/grid/connections/webrtc_test.py#L43-L81)) I am working with, I am trying to improve test coverage by testing a `try-except` block in a class' `__init__` method.

Stripping off the extra code from the source, the relevant code looks like:

```py
# webrtc.py

import asyncio
from loguru import logger
try:
    from asyncio import get_running_loop  # noqa Python >=3.7
except ImportError:  # pragma: no cover
    from asyncio.events import _get_running_loop as get_running_loop  # pragma: no cover

class WebRTCConnection:
    loop: Any

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        try:
            self.loop = get_running_loop()
        except RuntimeError as e:
            self.loop = None
            logger.error(e)
        
        if self.loop is None:
            self.loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
```

In a separate test file, I'd like to mock `RuntimeError` to test the `try except` block:

```py
# webrtc_test.py

from unittest.mock import patch
from unittest.mock import Mock

import asyncio
import pytest
from webrtc import WebRTCConnection

@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def test_init_patch_runtime_error() -> None:
    nest_asyncio.apply()

    with patch("webrtc.get_running_loop", return_value=RuntimeError):
        with pytest.raises(RuntimeError):
            WebRTCConnection()

@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def test_init_mock_runtime_error() -> None:
    nest_asyncio.apply()

    mock_running_loop = Mock()
    mock_running_loop.side_effect = RuntimeError
    with patch("webrtc.get_running_loop", mock_running_loop):
        with pytest.raises(RuntimeError):
            domain = Domain(name="test")
            WebRTCConnection()
```

Neither test would pass because neither would raise `RuntimeError`.

Additionally, I tried to mock `asyncio.new_event_loop` with `monkeypatch`:

```
# webrtc_test.py

from unittest.mock import patch
from unittest.mock import Mock

import asyncio
import pytest

from webrtc import WebRTCConnection

@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def test_init_new_event_loop(monkeypatch) -> None:
    nest_asyncio.apply()

    WebRTCConnection.loop = None
    mock_new_loop = Mock()
    monkeypatch.setattr(asyncio, "new_event_loop", mock_new_loop)
    WebRTCConnection()

    assert mock_new_loop.call_count == 1
```

This test also fails because the monkey patch is never called: `> assert mock_new_loop.call_count == 1 E assert 0 == 1`.

I'm wondering what I did wrong here and how could I successfully test the `__init__` method for this class?

Thanks a lot for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two problem shere:

1. You're setting the return value of `get_running_loop`, but an exception isn't a return value. If you want your mocked code to raise an exception, you need to configure a [side_effect](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#quick-guide).
2. Your code catches the `RuntimeError` and doesn't re-raise is: you simply set `self.loop = None` and log an error. This means that even when you successfully raise a `RuntimeError` from `get_event_loop`, that exception will never be visible to your tests because it is consumed by your code.

If you were to mock your `logger` object, you can check that `logger.error` was called with the exception. E.g.:

```
@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def test_init_patch_runtime_error() -> None:
    nest_asyncio.apply()

    with patch("webrtc.logger") as mock_logger:
        with patch("webrtc.get_running_loop", side_effect=RuntimeError()):
            WebRTCConnection()
            assert isinstance(mock_logger.error.call_args[0][0], RuntimeError)
```

---

**Edit**: W/r/t to checking the `self.loop = None` part, I would probably rewrite the code like this:

```
class WebRTCConnection:
    loop: Any = None

    def __init__(self) -> None:
    ┆   try:
    ┆   ┆   self.loop = get_running_loop()
    ┆   except RuntimeError as e:
    ┆   ┆   logger.error(e)

    ┆   if self.loop is None:
    ┆   ┆   self.loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
```

And then when testing, you would need to mock a return value for `new_event_loop`. I would probably get rid of the nested `with` statements and just use the `patch` decorator on the function instead:

```
@pytest.mark.asyncio
@patch('webrtc.logger')
@patch('webrtc.get_running_loop', side_effect=RuntimeError())
@patch('webrtc.asyncio.new_event_loop', return_value='fake_loop')
async def test_init_patch_runtime_error(
    mock_new_event_loop,
    mock_get_running_loop,
    mock_logger
) -> None:
    nest_asyncio.apply()

    rtc = WebRTCConnection()
    assert isinstance(mock_logger.error.call_args[0][0], RuntimeError)
    assert rtc.loop == 'fake_loop'
```

...but obviously you could do the same thing with either a series of nested `with patch(...)` statements or a single long `with` statement.

Comment: I've updated the answer to address your comment.

Comment: Thanks. I deleted my original comment as the question wasn't really valid (I was not the author of the source code and did not fully digest the code). I could also put monkeypatch directly in the first code you suggested with `mock_new_loop = Mock()` and `monkeypatch.setattr(asyncio, "new_event_loop", mock_new_loop)` and `assert mock_new_loop.call_count == 1`. That seems to pass as well. But your suggestion below is even better :)